# Why I can't get callback via AJAX in Flask project?

Tags: python, flask

This program is based on Flask, it allows user to click 'LIKE' button to increase 1 like_count for the post.

with follows, I can not POST the 'postid' to '/like' function and can not get callback from it. Terminal shows TypeError:

> like() missing 1 required positional argument: 'postid'.

## like.html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="like(this, {{ post.post_id }});">LIKE({{ post.like_count }})</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function like(doc, postid){
     $.ajax({
         url:'{{ url_for('main.like') }}',
         data:{postid:postid},
         type:'POST',
         success:function(callback){
            var temp = 'LIKE' + callback;
            $(doc).text(temp)
         }
     });                        
    }
</script>
```

## views.py：

```
@main.route('/like', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def like(postid):          
    post = Post.query.filter_by(post_id=postid).first()
    new_count = post.like_count + 1
    post.like_count = new_count +1
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return Response(new_count)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're posting `postid` as form data, not as a url value.  Remove the argument from the view signature and get the value from `request.form`.

```
def like():
    postid = request.form['postid']
```